# Instance and storage reliability

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm new to Google Cloud SQL.
Usually, all cloud instances has ephemeral storage. In case of shutdown, crash, reboot, maintenance and so on, data stored on ephemeral disk is lost.

In other words, in a cloud words, data loss *is expected*.

What about Google Cloud SQL ? Are my data stored on a persistent and redundant disk ? What happens to my data in case of crashes, maintenance, reboots and so on ?

I know that backups are needed (as always), but is data loss something to expect like with any cloud instance? Is HA and read replicas mandatory even if my application doesn't need 99.99% SLAs ? In example, if Cloud SQL should fail for some minutes and the be back online (with all of my data), is not an issue.

What do you think ?

tl;dr: are Cloud SQL instances stored on persistent disks or on storages with RAID or similiar systems to prevent data-loss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of Google Cloud SQL is actually running on a Google Compute Engine VM. That means that the database is stored in a persistent disk [1]. It suppose that these disk are very secure, however, the recommendation is constantly create backups [2]    (although data loss is something not expected)

On the other hand, HA is not mandatory. In fact you have to explicitly request it feature when you create an instance [3].

It looks like you already saw the SLA of Cloud SQL, but check it in case you didn’t yet [4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/data-centers/storage#block_storage
[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#what_backups_provide
[3] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha
[4] https://cloud.google.com/sql/sla

Comment: So, in case of planned maintenance, instance migration by Google, and so on, my data are kepts safe and available (when maintenance completes), right ?

Comment: that's right, but don't forget to constantly create backups as a good practice.